# Idiomatic way to get and remove an entry from a Map

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I need to get and remove an entry from a `Map` like that:

```
def foo(key: Int, m: Map[Int, String]): (Option[String], Map[Int, String]) = 
  m.get(key).map(v => (Some(v), m - key)).getOrElse((None, m))
```

It works but looks clumsy and suboptimal since it performs both `get` and `remove`.
What is an idiomatic way to do it ?

Comment: The `-` is safe, if the key doesn't exist nothing happens so I would just `map.get(k) -> (m - k)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you. Your suggestion `map.get(k) -> (m - k)` looks much simpler than the code above.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an immutable Map, you would need to explicitly handle `get` and `removal`. It cannot be done as a single effect.

However, if can use a `mutable.Map` instead, you may do something like this:

```
val map = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
map += ("hey" -> "value")

val r: Option[String] = map.remove("hey")
```

Comment: I do not think than suggestion mutability just because the immutable solution feels too boilerplate is a good recommendation.

Comment: The suggestion is not to move away from immutable map to mutable map, but to rather suggest if mutable map would serve his purpose better if he is adding and removing.

Comment: Why? An immutable map serves as well the purpose of adding and removing values. You just create copies every time. Your argument would imply that immutable collections only serve as read only constants, but we all know that immutable collections can _(should)_ be used for modelling business problems that imply some change of state, we just are explicit about those changes. Mutable data structures are only valid when either performance or memory footprint are primary concern. Or when used in the isolation of just one method to reduce complexity of an implementation.

Comment: There is nothing that you have written that I disagree with. And well put. But reiterating to what I mentioned before, from the limited information author has put, may be mutable map would work alright, to avoid creating intermediate collections with '-'.

Comment: Ok, I agree with what you say. I did a little edit just to be able to remove the downvote.